# Python error with install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, windows-xp

When I run Python build setup command I get this error:

```
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install 


command 1: python setup.py install
command 2:easy_install --dir setup.py
```

But I have built successfully with command python setup.py sdist

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7

[image: Please refer my image]

Comment: Put the image here please. Don't put an external link. Please!